# issue in google place search call back function

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, google-places-api, asynchronous

I am running into strange issue. This is regarding google Place search of type "textsearch". I am searching map for the results with a keyword and have a callback function to create result ("li" in html).

The problem is that google Place search api only gives 20 results for text search. To retrieve more results, we have to call `pagination.nextPage()`. This calls the same callBack function and gives more result.

So,

My code is

```
var request = {query: 'pizza in newyork'};
var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
service.textSearch(request, callBack1);

function callBack1(results, status,pagination)  {
    for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
      var place = results[i];
      //add place as li
    }
    if (pagination.hasNextPage) {
        pagination.nextPage();
    }
            doOtherOperation();
}

function doOtherOperation() {
     //do manipulations on "li" which are created from callBack1
}
```

The problem is that `doOtherOperation()` starts executing before callBack1() completes execution.

Anybody can help? how to make sure that callBack1 will executed fully (including recursive calls by `pagination.nextPage()`)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not an expert, but looks like a small logic flaw, so I will do it this way:

```
if (pagination.hasNextPage) {
    pagination.nextPage();
    }
else
   {
   doOtherOperation();
   }
```

Otherwise doOtherOperation(); gets called each time regardless of the fact that you have to go trough nextPage again.

Hope it helps

Comment: Ya, I thought so, let me try this and will see!

Comment: It worked!, why I did not think this easy one! :) Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

try to wrap `doOtherOperation()` with `setTimeout(function() { /*  */}, 0)`

UPDATE... how about that?

```
var flag = false;

function callBack1(results, status,pagination)  {
    /* since callback1 is the same callback for textSearch() and nextPage() - 
        you need to call dootherOperation at the beginning of statement */
    if (flag) {
        doOtherOperation();
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
      var place = results[i];
      //add place as li
    }
    if (pagination.hasNextPage) {
        flag = true;
        pagination.nextPage();
    }
    else {
        flag = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: does not help! the issue is still there :(

Comment: I'm not sure if this will work. You can have 3 pages or results. I understood that he wanted to call `doOtherOperation()` when all information is collected.